# Linking to other files and keep the formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel VBA to get cell contents from a number of unopened workbooks in a directory.  The code I am using is like so...

```
Sub Test()

Dim ctr
Range("A3:f200") = ""
Range("k7") = Date
MyPath = "U:\ATTENDANCE ADULT 12\"
myname = Dir(MyPath, vbNormal)
ctr = 3
Do While myname <> ""
  If myname <> "." And myname <> ".." Then
    If (GetAttr(MyPath & myname) And vbNormal) = vbNormal Then
      If ctr = 3 Then Range("h1") = "='" & MyPath & "[" & myname & "]TRMII'!R10C1"
      Range("a" & ctr) = myname
      Range("b" & ctr) = "='" & MyPath & "[" & myname & "]TRMII'!R12C6"
      Range("c" & ctr) = "='" & MyPath & "[" & myname & "]TRMII'!R4C5"
      Range("d" & ctr) = "='" & MyPath & "[" & myname & "]TRMII'!R2C13"
      Range("e" & ctr) = "='" & MyPath & "[" & myname & "]TRMII'!R3C13"
      Range("f" & ctr) = "='" & MyPath & "[" & myname & "]TRMII'!R8C5"

      ctr = ctr + 1
    End If
  End If
  myname = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

It works great!  But I would like it to get not only the contents of the cells, but also the formatting. Is that possible?  Please advise.  Thanks!

Comment: Not with formulas.  Currently you are inserting formulas that link to the value of the target sheets.  You will need to use copy and paste/pastespecial to do it.

Comment: Do I need to open each workbook then?

Comment: Yes you will need to open each workbook and copy and paste each cell or range desired.